# How does Vue.js know this markup is the component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How does Vue.js know `<my-component>` equals/is `MyComponent`?

```
<template>
    <!-- Vue.js correctly inserts the component here
         But how does it know my-component = MyComponent? -->
    <my-component></my-component>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
import MyComponent from '../MyComponent.vue'

export default {

    components: {
        MyComponent
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: [I hope you read this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html)

Comment: @C2486 thanks that answers my question. If you create an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a fairly standard convention that APIs like Vue has will convert between kebab-case and PascalCase / camelCase because HTML is case insensitive.

See this info here:  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-name-casing-in-JS-JSX-strongly-recommended

More specifically it "knows" because vue contains methods to parse camelCase, kebab-case (snake-case) in strings, props, etc.

You can see how this might be done in the `util.js` file found in `vue/src/shared/util.js` around line 157.   see  `camelize` and `hyphenate`

I believe PascalCase is simply handled using `camelize` combined with the`capitalize` utility. Something like...

```
var camelized = camelize();
var pascalized = capitalize(camelized);
```